# Accessing Rails route helpers in route redirect block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, url-routing

Is there a convenient way to access route helpers in the route redirect block?

```
get 'new-page' => 'home#new_page', as: :new_page

get 'old-page', to: redirect(:new_page)
# or something like:
get 'old-page', to: redirect { |_, _| new_page_path }
```

**Edit:**

This solution works, but it's ugly:

```
get 'old-page', to: redirect { |_, _| Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.new_page_path }
```

Comment: Since the route helpers are dynamically created based on the routes file, I'm not sure it would work _inside_ the routes file. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, this solution works, but it's ugly: 
`get 'old-page', to: redirect { |_, _| Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.new_page_path } `

Answer (score 2):

It looks like OP solved their own problem, but I wanted to Answer that this is a good solution:

```rb
get 'old-page', to: redirect { Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.new_page_path }
```

And if one gets tired of writing `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` it's easy to define a helper method for that:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'old-page', to: redirect { url_helpers.new_page_path }
  get 'another-page', to: redirect { url_helpers.new_page_path }

  def url_helpers
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining the route of 'new-page' immediately above, why do you need to use the path helper at all? Isn't this all you need?

```
get 'old-page', to: redirect('new-page')
```

Or am I missing something?

If you need dynamic segments, you can still do something like:

```
get 'old-page/:this_is_dynamic', to: redirect('new-page/%{this_is_dynamic}')
```

Comment: What if the route is nested in multiple scopes/namespaces?